# How to reduce codeigniter view loading time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've a customers table by that I am getting all customers data
which have around 15,000 rows, using the query

```
select * from customers order by createdate desc;
```

index is created on `createdate` column.
Query is fine not taking that much of time

But the ci view to load the page taking arround 2 minute
I checked this using profiling

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

output

```
             BENCHMARKS  
            Loading Time: Base Classes                              0.0231
            Header                                                  0.0010
            customersView                                           0.5493 //this is a view taking more time
            Footer                                                  0.0554
            Controller Execution Time ( Customers / CustomersController )   1.2286
            Total Execution Time                                    1.2519



             DATABASE:  vidyanidhi   QUERIES: 2  (Hide)
            0.0535      select * from customers where id=2568 
            0.1799      select * from customers order by createdate desc
```

How to reduce the loading time of this view in ci. Please someone help me.

Comment: check  your console to overview script , other js , css and image loading time

Comment: @Shafiqul Islam They are taking too less time around 10ms

Comment: do you show your code?

Comment: are you using pagination ?

Comment: @hrishi I am using DataTable() plugin to load in table. without this also view is too slow

Comment: You are loading all 15,000 rows in single time in datatable. Try server side data table https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: You can also use datatable with ajax and set bDeferRender to true it will improve speed of loading data in table http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Tips to Reduce loading time in CI.

1. Download all the Online resources such as JQUERY, Bootstrap and all. Add those in folder call `assets` outside the application folder and call it to your's
2. if you are using common library(JQUERY, Bootstrap) use `.min` versions.
3. Optimize images much as possible.
4. Check all the Links(AJAX, JS) with error encountering(500, 404 like) its get more time to load the view.

Comment: Using all above Tips

Comment: so whats is customer view ?

Comment: It is a mvc view

Comment: load the view without this page and check

Comment: Checked It is fast enough

Comment: After checking the total execution time is around 0.1732

Comment: Where is the problem I bored with this.

Comment: Yes to improve performance I used DataTable plugin of jquery with ajax and generated table data using columndef attribute of datatable. Here is link of youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgD24a9gxXw

Answer (score 0):

Place additional bench marks in your views models and controllers to give a further break down. This will help you get a better idea of what each section is doing

`$this->benchmark->mark('my_controller_start');`

`$this->benchmark->mark('my_controller_end');`

Also to make you query slightly faster don't do select *, only grab the data you need from the table unless you need absolutely every thing then keep you select *

ex. `select id, name , email`

Further more if you are returning 15,000 results to the view you should try CI pagination to return them in chunks

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I tried benchmark, View only taking more time and for pagination i am using jquery DataTable() plugin..